# CreateDC fails with error code 0

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm printing using CreateDC, passing in a valid DEVMODE structure and getting NULL returned which indicates an error but GetLastError returns 0.

```
m_hDC = ::CreateDC(L"WINSPOOL", PrinterName, NULL, pDevMode);
if (m_hDC == NULL)
{
 throw Exception(GetLastError(), __LINE__, _T(__FILE__));
}
```

This is working for all of my customers apart from one, any ideas?

Comment: [`CreateDCW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdcw) doesn't set the calling thread's last error code. Calling `GetLastError()` will return a meaningless value regardless of whether the call to `CreateDCW()` succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the thunking spooler api's.

The software is a 32 bit Windows service running on a 64 bit system.

It seems that only one user/session can print at a time from a 32 bit process, the next user has to wait for splwow64.exe to timeout (or kill it) before they can print.

It is covered in a [KB972616](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972616/en-us) <sup>[archive](https://archive.ph/yPKSg)</sup> from Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that `pDevMode` is valid?  You could try using a `NULL` pointer here in case the `DEVMODE` is the issue.

Comment: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer].